# Having a set of strings, count all the permutations with repetitions that make up a palindrome string

Tags: python, loops, optimization

Example:

```
3
madam
im
adam
```

Output should be 3 because the palindrome results are:
`["madam" + "im" + "adam"] ; ["madam" + "adam" + "adam"] ; ["madam" + "madam" + "madam"]`

This is the code I wrote:

```
import itertools

n = int(input())

x = []
for i in range(0, n):
    x += input()

x = [''.join(list(x)) for x in itertools.product(x, repeat=n)]

tot = 0

for e in x:
    if e==e[::-1]:
        tot+=1

print(tot)
```

This has probably a O(n^n) complexity, I need a code that can run up to 1000+ inputs, this isn't feasible with this script. Is there an alternative solution or a whole new way to solve the problem without resorting to `itertools.product`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use assignment expressions to filter the palindromes while iterating over `itertools.product`

```
x = [e for x in itertools.product(x, repeat=n) if (e := ''.join(x)) == e[::-1]]
print(len(x))
```

Comment: as a counting problem the resulting term in the comprehension _can_ be setted to constant, i.e. equal to `1`

Comment: This is indeed a clearer way of writing it however the complexity doesn't decrease and the underlying problem doesn't get fixed